# Finding places to play Magic the Gathering games

Tags: magic-the-gathering

A friend of mine recently got MTG for the XBox and is talking us into getting real cards.

I'm all up for starting but I dread the idea of playing the same two people over and over with no change epically since one of them is over competitive and exploits every loophole he can to win.

Does anyone know of any a reliable (not just google it) way to find places where people play MTG?

Comment: welcome to the site!  I have edited your question to keep the question more general; asking for places to play in a specific city is too localized and could possibly be closed.

Answer (score 13):

As for your location-specific needs, I don't know that many people can speak to that.  However, for the more generalized "How do I find more places/people to play Magic with," here are a few answers:

- Wizards of the Coast has a [Store and Event Locator](http://ww2.wizards.com/StoreAndEventLocator/)
- Check your LGSs (Local Gaming Stores) - many will either run Friday Night Magic, regular events, or casual play days
- Look online for people or groups that play in your area (e.g. something like Craigslist or http://www.meetup.com in the US - not sure about the UK)
- Teach other people to play

Besides those, there's always Magic the Gathering: Online - yes, it's another place to spend money on Magic (and you don't physically own the cards), but lots of the older (and less-played newer) cards can be found very cheaply, and it shouldn't be hard to put together a decent collection and play online.

Comment: there are no LGS

Comment: @Skeith, the Store and Event Locator show two stores, both around 8 miles away.  Beyond that, it seems like finding or teaching other people (or playing online) are your best bet.

Answer (score 4):

### [NearbyGamers](http://nearbygamers.com/)

This website is dedicated to solving your problem.

Caveat: I haven't used it in years, because I have all the gamers I need.