# Where can I play magic in Berlin?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am in Berlin right now. Does anybody knows some good pub, where it is possible to play Magic: The Gathering?

Comment: This question is too localized as is, and will probably be closed unless edited. If you change it to something more general, like "How can I find a local group to play Magic the Gathering with?" it would be much better.

Comment: @shujaa Actually, "too localized" is no longer a reason for closing. I'm not sure what close reason should be used.

Comment: @Pablo Well, let's just go with "this question should be edited to be more general, because general solutions exist and would probably be helpful to a lot more people". I'd much prefer to see edits than to place it on hold.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is not within the scope of a board game Q&A site to recommend individual available pubs to play a game in.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs, I disagree because part of the the gaming experience is the social aspect of meeting people to play, especially for MTG. Unless you're playing with friends or on MTGO, knowing where the local game store is located is necessary to play. I agree with shujaa that if edits are needed, we should edit it to be more general, i.e. "Where can you find a place to play MTG?".

Comment: Generalized version of question: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3840/finding-places-to-play-magic-the-gathering-games?rq=1

Comment: Cannot recast my vote to close, but this should be put on hold as both opinion based question  (asking for good pub) and a duplicate, not really off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Well you could go to http://www.dailymtg.com and Enter Berlin into the Magic Locator app on the Left Side of the webpage.

That will tell you where all the game stores that sell Magic: The Gathering are and what events they are running.